# How can I write an Elixir mapping function such that it can adding items in each list?

Tags: algorithm, mapping, elixir

how can i apply a map function that takes a function f and 2 list l1 and l2 and returns the list that is produced by applying the function to one element from each of the list in turn?

some pseudocode

```
function add(a1,a2) {return a1 + a2}

map2(add, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

And this would produce a list

```
[5,7,9]
```

Here is what I've done so far

```
 Enum.map(list, fn n -> IO.puts n + Enum.each(list2, fn z -> z end)
```

Comment: FYI: This site is created not to help _you_ to solve _your_ issues, but to help as many people as possible, and for the sake of future visitors you are obliged to mark the best answer as correct (I’d suggest marking Dogbert’s one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function in Erlang's `lists` module which does exactly this: `lists:zipwith/3`. There's no wrapper for that in Elixir's `Enum` module though.

```
iex(1)> :lists.zipwith(fn a, b -> a + b end, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[5, 7, 9]
```

`fn a, b -> a + b end` can be shortened to taking a reference to the `+` operator:

```
iex(2)> :lists.zipwith(&Kernel.+/2, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with firstly [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2)ing inputs and then applying the function:

```
iex(1)> defmodule M do
...(1)>   def add({a1, a2}), do: a1 + a2
...(1)> end
iex(2)> Enum.zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]) |> Enum.map(&M.add/1)
#⇒ [5, 7, 9]
```

Or, using a comprehension [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1):

```
iex(3)> for {i1, i2} <- Enum.zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]), do: i1 + i2
#⇒ [5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: thank you, that really helped :D btw what does the &M.add/1 means?

Comment: It is a syntactic sugar for `fn p1 -> M.add(p1) end`.

Comment: a = [1,2,3]; 
b = [4,5,6];
Enum.zip(a,b) |> Enum.map(fn {x,y} -> x + y end)

Comment: @ShashidharMayannavar this is the variant 2 from my answer, written in less idiomatic Elixir. The question clearly stated: how to apply _a self-written function_, that is why I showed var. 1.

Answer (score 0):

By way of update in Elixir 1.12 there will be an Enum.zip_with/3 function:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L3349